# remove duplicated parameters in url with javsacript or angular

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters

I need to remove any duplicated parameters if exists to be written one time in URL

e.g

```
http://localhost:4200/res/?someName1=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&somethingName2=specialities%3D49__name%3D%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&back_spec_title=Eye&back_spec_title=Eye&back_spec_id=17555&back_spec_id=17555&back_sur_title=Lasik&back_sur_title=Lasik&back_sur_id=599&back_sur_id=599&screen_type=surgery
```

as you can see :

```
back_spec_title=Eye 
back_spec_id=17555
back_sur_title=Lasik
back_sur_id=599
```

every parameter of those repeated two times

Desired output :

```
http://localhost:4200/res/?someName1=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&somethingName2=specialities%3D49__name%3D%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%86&back_spec_title=Eye&back_spec_id=17555&back_sur_title=Lasik&back_sur_id=599&screen_type=surgery
```

Comment: How do you build out the url?

Comment: i'm using `router navigate` for testing .. but in real world those parameters from laravel backend .

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me: Instead of relying on JS to remove the duplicated query parameters, you should look into your server to why it's doing that at the first place.

Comment: i know but i need that for testing this is a static link with static params through `router navigate` function  .

Comment: `let url = url.split("&") // returns an array with url parts split at each "&" character.`    Then comparing elements in an array is easy...

Comment: @ISAE yeah i know that but i need to check how many times then remove repeats or deuplicates params if exists .. will be appreciated if i found help .. thanks .

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)